# how do I fix HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized?

Tags: iis

So I've come across a problem, what I am trying to do is "Check if the python file is ready to execute" as verbatim by my CS professor. So here I what I have done so far:

-Enabled Directory Browsing

-Added a new Script Map

-Linked the executable to the python executable of my python project

-Changed its directory to a new folder (as instructed)

-Created a New Python File with this code in it:
print("Content-Tytpe: text/html\n");
number1 = 1

```
while number < 10:
    print("Hello Python World! <br>");
    number = number+1
```

-and finally clicked on *"Browse *.80"**

I clicked on "test.py" (the python file) and this showed up:
[image]

I researched a couple of fixes in this site and among others and this is what I have tried:
-Checked the permissions in the folder and made added a new permission for Everyone with Full Control Access

-Checked Authentication and Anonymous Authentication and set it to Application Pool Identity, both on the Desktop and the Default Website

-I even went to go as far as resetting my PC to check if some other third party application is affecting it

I am really at the end of my rope here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to the steps below.

1. In IIS, select your **site** -> Double click on **Authentication** -> Select **Anonymous authentication**-> Right-click on it and select **Edit** option.
2. Select a **Specific user** option. Set **IUSR**, click **OK**.

[image]

3. Go to the **site** folder-> open its **properties**-> go to **Security** tab-> Make sure **IIS_USRS** has **Read & execute**, **List folder contents**, **Read** permissions.

[image]

After that try to visit the page again.

If the issue persists, try to check whether you are able to visit any HTML file in that folder or not.